# TopTabNavigator add custom icon

Tags: react-native

I'm following an tutorial and I got a little stuck.

I'm trying to add an custom icon in a react native tab navigator but I had not been lucky and hope some fellow member can guide me in the right direction.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, Image} from 'react-navigation';
import FoldersList from '../screens/FoldersList';

const Routes = {
   Home: {
       screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={0}/>,
       navigationOptions: {
           title: 'Home'
       }
   },
   MyNewTab: {
       screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={1} createFolderTitle='Create new tab folder' />,
       navigationOptions: {
           title: 'MyNewTab'
       }
   },
   MyThirdTab: {
       screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={2} createFolderTitle='Create third tab folder'/>,
       navigationOptions: {
           tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
               return (<Image
                   style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                   source={{ require: "../../images/AddFolder.png" }}/>);}
       }
   },
};

const routeConfig = {
   swipeEnabled: false,
   tabBarOptions: {
       style: {
           backgroundColor: '#013a65',
         },
           renderIndicator: () => null, // Indicatorline under tabbar
           activeTintColor:'red',
           inactiveTintColor:'#ffffff',
           }, 
           }, 
     };

export default TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
   ...Routes
}, routeConfig);
```

Comment: You should have some kind of  "resource" file or similar (I don't know react), like that where you do something like this, `var myAwesomeIcon = "C:/./././myIcon.jpg`. And then you use your variable instead of what you just did.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Try  'source={require("../../images/AddFolder.png")}'

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: I did try 'source={require("../../images/AddFolder.png")}' but with no luck. It just says MyThirdTab.

Answer (score 4):

Hello here is a simple code:

**UPDATE**

```
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
   tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  // Note: By default the icon is only shown on iOS. Search the showIcon 
   option below.
     tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
     <Image
       source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
       style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
     />
   ),
 };

render() {
 return (
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
    title="Go to notifications"
  />
  );
 }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
   tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
   tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
   <Image
      source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
      style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
   />
  ),
 };

render() {
 return (
   <Button
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
     title="Go back home"
   />
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 26,
   height: 26,
  },
 });

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
   Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
   },
  Notifications: {
   screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
  }, {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
 });
```

According to the docs, the showIcon property is setted to **false** on Android ( https://web.archive.org/web/20171015002750/https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarTop-default-tab-bar-on-Android ).

**IF THE ABOVE CODE DO NOT WORKS FOLLOW THE BELLOW STEPS**:

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
   Displayed: {
     screen: MyHomeScreen,
     navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Favorites',
        tabBar: {
           icon: ({tintColor}) => (<Image
           source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
           style={{width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: tintColor}}
         />)
        },
      },
    },
    ...
```

or

```
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Foo Bar',
        tabBar: {
            icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <Image
                source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
                style={{width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: tintColor}}
              />
            ),
        }
      };
 ...
```

I really hope that some code help you...

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but the icons is working for me, I use the fontawesome. The problem I have is how to get a custom icon from my Image folder.

Answer (score 1):

if you until do not work if the codes bellow, please see this other code:

**UPDATE**

```
//Package json
//change "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "0.1.2"

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet,
  //use SafeAreaView to move the images away from the top of the phone
  SafeAreaView,
  Image} from 'react-native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
//imports the icons
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

export default class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView style = {{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'}} > 
        <AppTabNavigator/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

//homescreen and the text that is displayed on that page
class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <Text>Welcome to my Navigator! </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
//MyPage and the text that is displayed on that page
class MyPage extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <Text>My Page </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

//settings and the text that is displayed on that page
class SettingsScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <Text>Settings </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

//settings and the text that is displayed on that page
class ProfileScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <Text>Profile </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }




//ceated a topTabNavigator then moved the buttons to the bottom
const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="ios-home" color = {tintColor} size = {24}/>
      )
    }
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="ios-settings" color = {tintColor} size = {24}/>
    )
   }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
     // <Icon name="ios-profile" color = {tintColor} size = {24}/>
      <Image
          source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
             style={{
              marginLeft: 1,
              marginTop: 1,
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
              tintColor: '#FF3D00',
        }}
      />
    ) 
   }
  },
  MyPage: {
    screen: MyPage,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Page',
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name = "ios-body" color = {tintColor} size = {24} />
      )
    }
  }
},
{
  //starts the program on Home Screen
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  //orders the screens
  //order: ['Settings', 'Home'],
  //puts a color when that screen is activated in the tabs
  //activeTintColor: 'white',
  //Allows for icons(only) to appear on inactive tabs when you have more than 3 tabs
  shifting: true,
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  // swipeEnabled: true,
  // animationEnabled: false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'red',
    inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      borderTopWidth: 0.5,
      borderTopColor: 'grey'
    },
    // indicatorStyle: {
    //   height: 0
    // },
    showIcon: true
  }
})
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }
  });
```

the code to help you is this:

```
 Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
     // <Icon name="ios-profile" color = {tintColor} size = {24}/>
      <Image
          source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
             style={{
              marginLeft: 1,
              marginTop: 1,
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
              tintColor: '#FF3D00',
        }}
      />
    ) 
   }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, any chance you can show me how to add that into the tutorial code that I'm following. I don't think that I'm doing it all right and it gives me a minor error and a headache. :-)

Comment: can you put your code at expo and add here to my view?

Comment: I never tried expo and just spent some time on it right now with no luck.
I'm sorry about that.
I'm just trying to add it to the code at the top, 
I did try with adding it to my "MyThirdTab" but didn't succeed.
Maybe you can shine some magic on it. That would be like a lifesaver. :-)

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/material-design-bottom-swipe-animation

Comment: above is a snack, simple code in expo... just to your view, will work normally

Comment: the tricks is this: <Image
                  source={require('../assets/back.png')}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 1,
                    marginTop: 1,
                    width: 25,
                    height: 25,
                    tintColor: '#FF3D00',
                  }}
                />

Comment: I'm almost there, I can barely smell it, any chance you can look at my snack and read the bottom text. https://snack.expo.io/BkS4SPUAB

Comment: yes. i will read and leave some comments there.. the problem is that i have no entire code that you have maked and then, its hard to know where is the error that you get...

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/material-design-bottom-swipe-animation

Comment: In my code above when I add <Image source={require('../assets/back.png')} style={{ marginLeft: 1, marginTop: 1, width: 25, height: 25, tintColor: '#FF3D00', }} /> then my error is, that it want a string or a class/function in the code above and I'm unsure how to do that correct.

Comment: I recommend that you change your code to my code, will have the same result, and my type of code is more "correct and easy"... your type of code contain some errors about structure.